# Link a file extension to an app

Tags: powershell

I was wondering if it would be possible to create PowerShell script that would link a certain file extension to an application.

For example: 
The .ntb extension has to be opened using the following application by default:
`C:\Program Files\SMART Technologies\Education Software\Notebook.exe`

Why would I need a script for this you ask?
It could indeed be done by using Run With and then ticking the Default box. However I need to perform this on about 150+ computers. So I'd think to run the script when booting once.

I am a newbie when it comes to PowerShell, so if anyone could give a "small" start, I would be grateful.

Comment: That setting is configured in the registry. You can push out registry key/value changes via GPO, no PowerShell required.

Comment: I would second @alroc, you almost certainly want [to do this via Group Policy](http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2011/09/how-to-use-group-policy-to-change-open-with-file-associations/), for consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a scripted solution I'd use the `cmd` built-ins `assoc` and `ftype`:

```
$prg = 'C:\Program Files\SMART Technologies\Education Software\Notebook.exe'
$ext = '.ntb'

& cmd /c "ftype SMART.Notebook=`"$prg`" %1"
& cmd /c "assoc $ext=SMART.Notebook"
```

The above can be run on remote hosts via the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet:

```
Invoke-Command -Computer HostA,HostB,... -ScriptBlock {
  $prg = 'C:\Program Files\SMART Technologies\Education Software\Notebook.exe'
  $ext = '.ntb'

  & cmd /c "ftype SMART.Notebook=`"$prg`" %1"
  & cmd /c "assoc $ext=SMART.Notebook"
}
```

Otherwise you'll have to edit the registry, in which case the deployment via group policy would be preferable, as others have already pointed out.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. However I have one question. Would this work on computers that have CMD disabled by a GPO? Powershell is no problem, however a most computers have their CMD disabled.

Comment: @SVT Might still work, depending on which users the policy applies to. If you're running the script as an admin user, and the policy is not applied to admin users, the code should still work.